# Why doesn't Ruby module inheritance work like class inheritance?

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have a module called `Flight` with both class and instance methods. I can get its methods into a class using `include`, `extend`, or both:

```
class Bat < Mammal
  # Add Flight's class methods to Bat.
  extend Flight

  # Add Flight's instance methods to Bat.
  include Flight
  ...
end
```

`include` will add `Flight` to `Bat.ancestors`, but `extend` will not.

My question is, **why is this different for modules than for classes**? When I subclass `Mammal`, I **always** get both class and instance methods at once. However, when I mix in a module, I **cannot** get both class and instance methods at once (unless I use the `self.included` hook or something like [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html)).

Is there a language-design issue behind this difference?

Comment: Well, there has to be some difference to justify the existence of a separate entity, right? :)

Answer (score 10):

Both `Module#include` and `Object#extend` are used to add the **instance methods** of a `Module` to an `Object`.
Given the module:

```
module Flight
    def can_fly?
        true
    end
end
```

`Module#include` is used to add (or *mix in*) the instance methods of a module to the instance methods of a class or a module:

```
class Bat < Mammal
    include Flight
end

a = Bat.new()
a.can_fly?        # true
```

It actually affects the `Object#is_a?` method, so:

```
a.is_a? Flight     # true
```

`Module#include` is a *private method*, so it can only be called with *function notation* when defining a class or another module:

```
class Bat < Mammal
    self.include Flight     # NoMethodError: private method called
end
```

`Object#extend` adds the instance methods of a module as **singleton methods** to the object on which it's called, so you can do this:

```
b = Mammal.new()
b.extend Flight
b.can_fly?           # true
b.is_a? Flight       # true

c = Mammal.new()
c.can_fly?           # NoMethodError: undefined method
```

And only `b` will have the instance methods from `Flight`; other `Mammal` objects won't.

When calling `Object#extend` inside a class definition, the methods are added to the eigenclass of the class you're defining.
This is the important difference between the two methods when using them inside a class definition, because the methods are added as **class methods**:

```
class Bat < Mammal
    extend Flight
end

Bat.can_fly?     # true

d = Bat.new
d.can_fly?       # NoMethodError: undefined method
```

Answer (score 3):

"When I subclass `Mammal`, I always get both class and instance methods at once"

That's because `Bat` class as an object also inherited the instance methods from `Mammal` singleton class.

[image: Inheritance Graph]

Including a module into a class changes the method look up chain. So actually the class doesn't inherit any instance methods.

Extending a class with a module is same as extending any object. The class simply acquires the module's instance methods as class instance methods (ie. methods on the class object itself).

Answer (score 3):

I would like to address one part of your question:

> `include` will add `Flight` to `Bat.ancestors`, but `extend` will not.

*extend* is not the same as *include* so it does something different obviously... You can think of *extend* being equal to an *include* on the class' metaclass.

Have a look at the following example:

```
module M
end

class A
  include M
end

# then you will see M within A's ancestors as you know
A.ancestors # => [A, M, Object...]


class B
  # the following is roughly the same as extend M:
  class <<self
    include M
  end
end

# then you will see M within B's metaclass' ancestors
MetaclassOfB = class <<B; self; end
MetaclassOfB.ancestors # => [M, Class, Module...]
```

So, since *extend* is like an *include* on the metaclass, you see the extended modules showing up in the metaclass' ancestor chain...